# How to check current page has records in pagination in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

In my application I have implemented pagination 10 per record if user is in 3rd (x page) page it will display 10 records.I have search option in application if user search from 3rd page if the 3rd page doesn't have record .I need to navigate to 1st page 
can anybody tell how to implement

Thanks

Comment: Post your code or create a fiddle and share the link.

Comment: Why not simple redirect to page 1 when they do a search, like Google does.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you implementing custom pagination . There are various table library Which support server side rendering and pagination searching all the staff . It support all the staff .
I recommend to use this.
https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/